# can we create database checkpoints for Web applications?(testing)

Tags: testing, qtp

Its regarding QTP

**can we create database checkpoints for Web applications**

actually while creating database checkpoints we have to create DSN . 
So my question is can we create DSN for remote databases hosted on some other server.

Please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, We can create. but you should have the DB access i mean  to know the db username and password.

Comment: can you elaborate the process.......say username is abc and pass is xyz and database is hosted for sdf.com

Comment: If you can create a DSN on your local pc for the database, then you can use the database checkpoint.

Comment: Ping sdf.com from command prompt and find the host IP Say 122.64....Use this IP in Server Host. User name abc and password xyz You can connect the DB.